# In outloouk, file name received contains wrong characters

Tags: java, outlook

In my java application, I want to send an e-mail using the MimeMessageHelper:

My file name is: âTestFileüa.PNG

my code is here:

```
SimpleMailMessage mail= new SimpleMailMessage(templateMessage);
mail.setTo(personMail);
mail.setSubject(subject);
mail.setText(content);
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
try {
          MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
          messageHelper.setFrom(mail.getFrom());
          messageHelper.setTo(mail.getTo());
          messageHelper.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
          messageHelper.setText(mail.getText());     
          messageHelper.addAttachment(fileName, new ByteArrayResource(attchmentFile));
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The file is correcttly sent, but in outlook, the special characters of my file aren't correctly displayed.

[image]

---

Answer (score -1, accepted):

before this line,

```
messageHelper.addAttachment(fileName, new ByteArrayResource(attchmentFile));
```

I added :

```
fileName = MimeUtility.encodeText(filename);
```

and this work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with the encoding of the filename.  I would try setting an appropriate character encoding when creating the mime helper object.  For example:

```
 MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = 
         new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Well I suggest that you 1) check that the filename has not been mangled before you get to this code, and 2) examine the mime encoded message with "od" or the Windows equivalent to see if the problem is there or in Outlook itself.